# How can I make my smooth third person movement stop jittering?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

So I have been stuck on player movement for 15 hours total. My player jitters while it moves. I notice that the jitters aren't bad if:
A) I put CamPos code in the same lateUpdate() Function as PlayerMovement code
B) If I lower the fixed timestep under Time in project settings (makes jitter less notable)
I want to make it so that my player doesn't jitter using the right methods. My player has isKinematic off because it causes him to go through walls. I move using rigidbody movePosition because I don't know how to use rb.velocity to make the player move in the same direction as the camera.

I am using a camera for the third person and using rigidbody for movement.
Here's my current code on the player PlayerMovement:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;

    public Rigidbody rb;

    public Transform camPos;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        camPos = Camera.main.transform;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
            rb.MovePosition(transform.position + (camPos.forward * speed));
        if (Input.GetKey("s"))
            rb.MovePosition(transform.position + (-camPos.forward * speed));
        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
            rb.MovePosition(transform.position + (camPos.right * speed));
        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
            rb.MovePosition(transform.position + (-camPos.right * speed));
    }
}
```

Here's my current code on the camera CamPos:

```
//Hakeem Thomas
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CamPos : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float smoothTime = 0.5F;
    private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

    public GameObject player;

    private float mouseX, mouseY;
    public int mouseX_Speed, mouseY_Speed;
    
    //mouseSensitivity
    public int turnSpeed;

    void getMouseXY()
    {
        mouseX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * smoothTime;
        mouseY -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * smoothTime;
    }



    void LateUpdate()
    {
        getMouseXY();
        // Define a target position above and behind the target transform
        Vector3 targetPosition = target.TransformPoint(new Vector3(0, 1.5f, -2.5f));

        // Smoothly move the camera towards that target position
        transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, targetPosition, ref velocity, smoothTime);
        transform.LookAt(target);

        target.rotation = Quaternion.Euler((mouseY * mouseY_Speed), (mouseX * mouseX_Speed), 0);
        player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, (mouseX * turnSpeed), 0);

    }
}
```

I also tried using Vector3's and input Axis to move, but it makes the player move in an awkward way(Controls tied to one direction). I also tried using cinemachine and turned off all my scripts on my camera to make sure the camera wasn't jittering.

Answer (score 0):

Rigidbody is the physic representation of your gameobject. The thing is you doesn't use the velocity / movement of the gameobject using dirrectly the `rb.MovePosition()`.

But it is fine ! according to the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) you have to enable the rigidbody "interpolation" to create a smooth transition between frames.

Hope i helped you and it will works for you !

**Edit**

- dont forget to multiply your vector by Time.fixedDeltaTime inside FixedUpdate()

Comment: Awesome. Didn't know if MovePosition was the right way of moving. I always wondered why you have to multiply Time.deltaTime in certain situations. Was never explained.

Comment: Time.deltaTime must be used in Update() function because it correspond to the time elapsed between the previous Update() call. And the Time.fixedDeltaTime is the same thing but for the FixedUpdate() function.

Comment: The fixedTimeDelta helped with the jitter but it still jitters. I'm still fine with it though.